# React: API url works in GET request but it gets changed in POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, url, axios, apprequests

I am trying to set the api urls for my react app. The GET endpoints work perfectly but when I make a post request the URL becomes the localhost URL without any reason.

I am using a Constants.js file where I check if the node environment is in development or production. This is how they look in production.

```
const dev = {
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
};

const prod = {
  url: "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/",
};

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

export const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? dev : prod;
```

Currently I have them inverted so that I can make requests to the server on heroku.

```
const prod = {
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
};

const dev = {
  url: "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/",
};

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

export const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? dev : prod;
```

Here I am importing the config and making a GET request with the variable works perfectly fine.

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

  axios
    .get(`${config.url}accounts/api/auth/user`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
      });
    });
};
```

Here is where it gets weird. When I make the POST request the URL gets changed to the localhost.

```
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    username,
    password,
  });

  axios
    .post(`${config.url}accounts/api/auth/login`, body, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAILED,
      });
    });
};
```

This is the error I get in the console

```
VM159:1 POST http://localhost:3000/undefinedaccounts/api/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see the URL gets changed to the localhost and an undefined is passed to the URL which I do not know from where it comes.

If someone has any idea of what is happening here I would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this would be by setting `baseURL`:

Either as a [default config](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults):

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
```

Or, as the baseURL of your axios custom [instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults):

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

---

#### Issue in your code:

When you wrote:

```
axios.post(`${config.url}accounts/api/auth/login`, body, config)...
```

where `config` is:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
```

and it has "headers" only, hence "url" is simply `undefined`. To fix it, you should add "url" property as well in `config` object.

Comment: I don't know how I was so blind that I did not see that the two variables had the same name when they should not. Thanks a lot really appreciate it!

Comment: It is because the variable that I exported with the URLs was also named config so there was a conflict in there. It is so hard to find this type of errors.

Comment: I understand. You can use TypeScript to identify these errors faster. Also, add "ESLint" extension to your IDE (maybe VS Code), it will also help you writing better code.

Comment: Yes probably I will learn typescript soon. Thanks a lot for the help have a nice day!